# How to submit a form html with React/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I own a wordpress site. I'm voting there. (Wp-Polls plugin)

How can I perform post action by going to form url in React Project? For example voting for the Bad option (value=2).

The HTML output of the WordPress site is as follows;

```
<form id="polls_form_1" class="wp-polls-form" action="/index.php" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="poll-answer-1" name="poll_1" value="1">
            <label>Good</label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="radio" id="poll-answer-2" name="poll_1" value="2">
            <label>Bad</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="button" name="vote" value="Vote" class="Buttons" onclick="poll_vote(1);">
</form>
```

I couldn't get a result by doing fetch operation. I think onclick poll_vote(1); I need to click the method.

```
fetch('https://xxxx.com/index.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {"poll_1" : "2"},
  })
```

Comment: Out of topic: But you should make sure to not use the same id on two different elements. So use `id="poll-1-answer-1"` and `id="poll-1-answer-2"` on your inputs

Comment: If you use `<input type="submit"` instead of `type="button"`, you don't need to have an onclick.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing inside onClick is "Calling Function" and that function should exist for this to work.
Make a new function like this and do the fetch operation there:

```
function poll_vote() {
  fetch('https://xxxx.com/index.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: {"poll_1" : "2"},
  })
}
```

Comment: These are two different projects. One is wordpress (e.g. xxxx.com), the other is a separate react project. Not on a single project. A method I will create called poll_vote() will not work.